# SPF and Gmail as mail client

Tags: email, spf, gmail

I have mail server hosted by some "3rd party provider" (https://www.neoserv.si/) and I want to use Gmail as email client. In Gmail I have set POP3 to copy all incoming messages and IMAP so I can send messages directly from Gmail.

I'm not sure if I need to configure **SPF** for Gmail client, since I'm sending messages over IMAP?

My current SPF record contains only ip of my "3rd party provider". Is this enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to make any alterations to your SPF records.  The mail is still being sent by the "3rd party provider" and not by the Gmail Mobile App on your phone/device.

All IMAP/POP are responsible for is the moving of messages between the 3rd party mail server and your mobile device; they aren't handling sending mail to other mail servers (which is when SPF comes into play).

So just leave your already working SPF records alone, you'll be just fine.